# Use a Thymeleaf template without including the fragment definition element?

Tags: thymeleaf

Let's say I have two Thymeleaf templates:

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header>foo</header>
<section>
    <div th:replace="fragments/main :: content"></div>
</section>
<footer>bar</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**fragments/main.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="content">
    <p>This is the main content.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I prevent Tymeleaf from including the `div` that defines the fragment in the composited output? That is, how do I get Thymleaf to generate the following output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header>foo</header>
<section>
    <p>This is the main content.</p>
</section>
<footer>bar</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header>foo</header>
<section>
    <div>
        <p>This is the main content.</p>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>bar</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `th:remove="tag"`. ([documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#removing-template-fragments))

**fragments/main.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="content" th:remove="tag">
    <p>This is the main content.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. I'll accept it as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively, you could try using `th:block` instead of `div` in `main.html`, like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<th:block th:fragment="content">
    <p>This is the main content.</p>
</th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, however, that this will slightly change the way `main.html` looks when viewed as raw HTML without preprocessing by Thymeleaf.

Comment: I'll give a +1 on that. It's a nice use of `th:block`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another simple way to acomplish this is using `th:replace="fragments/main :: content/text()">` as shown here: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451

Your **fragments/main.html** remains the same

The `th:replace` attribute changes in the **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header>foo</header>
<section>
    <div th:replace="fragments/main :: content/text()"></div>
</section>
<footer>bar</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps this method was not available 5 years ago when the question was asked, but I wanted to add it here for anyone who stumbles upon this question looking for a solution. I was having a similar problem and the `th:remove="tag"` didn't work for me.